# In what sense is $\sum_{r =1}^3 \epsilon^r_\mu \epsilon^r_\nu $ a projection operator?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, classical-electrodynamics, polarization

It is mentioned in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/158471/37286) that the completeness relation for the polarization vectors of a (massive) electromagnetic field
$$ \sum_\lambda \varepsilon^\mu(\lambda,k) \varepsilon^{\nu*}(\lambda,k) = - \eta^{\mu\nu} + \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{M^2}. $$
can be understood since $P_\epsilon^{\mu\nu} := \sum_\lambda \epsilon^\mu_\lambda(k)\epsilon^{*\nu}_\lambda(k)$ is a  projection operator.   How can this be understood? In particular, on whom does $P_\epsilon^{\mu\nu} $ act in order to project out what?

Answer (score 3):

Applying the operator $P^{\mu\nu}$ to a generic vector $v_\nu$,

$$
-P^{\mu\nu} v_\nu = v^\mu - \frac{k^\nu v_\nu}{M^2} k_{\mu} .
$$

That is, up to a sign, $P$ "removes" (projects out) from $v$ its component parallel to $k$ (assuming $k_\mu k^\mu = M^2$). Therefore, it projects any vector to the surface orthogonal to $k$.

Comment: perfect thanks! This explains how it works. Is there a good reason *why* it works? It's not entirely clear to me, why the sum over the polarization vectors should yield such a projection operator.

Comment: I figured it out. Nevermind. This is really just the standard linear algebra definition of a projection operator that projects onto the subspace spanned by the vectors.

Comment: Yes, the polarisation vectors are indeed a basis of the subspace orthogonal to $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to act with $P_\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$ on $k_\nu$.