# Why do I find different polarization vector completeness relations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization, scattering-cross-section

I am currently working on computing the cross section of Compton scattering in QED and in the process need to evaluate an expression of the following form:

$$ \sum_{\lambda}^{} \epsilon^{\mu} (\lambda,k) \, \epsilon^{\nu} (\lambda,k)$$

In my course’s lecture notes, it has been derived that this expression equates to:

$$ \sum_{\lambda}^{} \epsilon^{\mu} (\lambda,k) \, \epsilon^{\nu} (\lambda,k) = -\eta^{\mu \nu} + \frac{k^{\mu} k^{\nu}}{m^2}$$

as can also be seen [here](https://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph218/polsum.pdf) and in a familiar question on StackExchange [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/why-is-there-sometimes-an-additional-term-in-the-orthogonality-relations-for-the).

However, in some sources on the internet — like in formula (2.15) [in this source](https://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/ab1u06/teaching/qft/qft1/christmas_problems/2014/xmas_problem_solution.pdf) — I find the following expression that does not include the second term:

$$ \sum_{\lambda}^{} \epsilon^{\mu} (\lambda,k) \, \epsilon^{\nu} (\lambda,k) = -\eta^{\mu \nu} $$

My questions: Is one of these expressions wrong? If not, how can the occurence of these two forms in the different sources be explained? Could it be explained via the choice of gauge? What am I missing?

Comment: From your first source "The results above should be contrasted with the case of a spin-1 particle of mass $m\neq 0$". Is the particle that you're considering massive or massles?

Comment: Since these are polarization vectors of photons then I am of course considering massless particles. The electrons with whom they are scattering do have mass of course.